# BufferStrategy and Swing combined?

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-2d

BufferStrategy is part of AWT and often used with the Canvas class, but could it also be combined with a Swing UI without causing any window display problems or should I better use pure AWT in this case? Thanks for any answer.

Comment: What's your motivation behind the question?

Comment: Swing is double buffered by default so there is generally no reason to use a BufferStrategy.

Comment: I have read that BufferStrategy is much faster.

Answer (score 2):

BufferStrategy is not really part of AWT, even if it is in the package java.awt.image. All image-related classes are in the java.awt.image package for historical reasons. BufferStrategy appeared in Java 1.4, and by that time Swing was the recommended framework (as opposed to AWT).

You can therefore use BufferStrategy with Swing. It is not needed for normal Swing components, but it can be useful for games.

Comment: Thanks. That means that BufferStrategy is has nothing to do with heavy-weight components? Is BufferStrategy more powerful than the internal Swing double buffer?

Comment: It has nothing to do with heavyweight components. "Powerful" - depends on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

In a Swing image preview I used it like this:

```
public class ImagePreview extends JFrame {
    ...
    private final int BUFFERS = 2;
    private BufferStrategy bufferStrategy;
    ...
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (bufferStrategy == null) {
            this.createBufferStrategy(BUFFERS);
            this.bufferStrategy = this.getBufferStrategy();
        }
        ...
        for (int i = 0; i < BUFFERS; i++) {
            Graphics2D g2Buffered = (Graphics2D) bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
            g2Buffered.draw(...
            ...
            bufferStrategy.show();
            g2Buffered.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: But what if I don't want to create a fullscreen application and use a JFrame with a JMenu? Should I better use AWT in this case?

Comment: As you can see it is a JFrame with a buffered paint method.

Comment: As far as I know only java.awt.Canvas uses hardware acceleration, but this class is a subset of AWT.